# Best way to handle specific MySQL errors

Tags: mysql, rust

When inserting/updating a record, I'd like to handle certain errors like UNIQUE constraint violations on specific fields, so that I can, for example, display a suitable error message to the user, such as "A record with such name already exists". What is the best way to do that?

Looking at the `mysql` crate's source, I found these error enums:

```
pub enum Error {
    IoError(io::Error),
    CodecError(mysql_common::proto::codec::error::PacketCodecError),
    MySqlError(MySqlError),
    DriverError(DriverError),
    UrlError(UrlError),
    TlsError(native_tls::Error),
    TlsHandshakeError(native_tls::HandshakeError<std::net::TcpStream>),
    FromValueError(Value),
    FromRowError(Row),
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct MySqlError {
    pub state: String,
    pub message: String,
    pub code: u16,
}
```

And I tried this code in my app:

```
let res = tx.exec_drop("INSERT INTO ....", (&name, ));
if let Err(ref e) = res {
    if let MySqlError(me) = e {
        log::info!("MyErr A: {}", me.to_string());
        log::info!("MyErr B: {} / {} : {}", me.state, me.message, me.code);
    }
}
res?;
```

It prints:

```
MyErr A: ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'xxxxxx' for key 'some_table.some_unq_constr_name'
MyErr B: 23000 / Duplicate entry 'xxxxxx' for key 'some_table.some_unq_constr_name' : 1062
```

So I guess I could implement the check with something like this:

```
if me.code == 1062 && me.message.ends_with("for key 'some_table.some_unq_constr_name'") {
    // There you go...
}
```

Is this the best (safest) way to do the check or is there something better?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how you should do it. You should only compare the error code against the appropriate `mysql::ServerError` enum. In this case:

```rust
if me.code == mysql::ServerError::ER_DUP_ENTRY {
    // There you go...
}
```

If you're curious what a particular code's name is, you can check [the source code](https://docs.rs/mysql/latest/src/mysql/error.rs.html#374-1103).

Sadly [there is no way yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2783) to turn the `u16` back into the `ServerError` type automatically allowing you to just print the variant name in Rust. And it doesn't appear that the `mysql` crate implemented a method for that either.

Comment: Yes, using a constant, instead of the hardcoded 1062, is definitely better. But apart from that, is there anything else that could be improved? What kinda worries me is the string check that more or less relies on a certain MySQL error message format. I guess I could make the check less likely to break, in case MySQL decide to change the msg format at some point (for example, just checking for substrings `"some_table"` and `"some_unq_constr_name"`). But that still feels a bit unsafe...